# ASP.NET-Identity: how to limit UserName length?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

How can I limit the length of `UserName` field in the table `AspNetUsers`?

Neither this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required, MaxLength(15)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

}
```

or this:

`modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(x => x.UserName).HasMaxLength(15);`

works.

I need this because setting an `Index` on an `nvarchar(max)` gives me this error message:

> Column 'UserName' in table 'dbo.AspNetUsers' is of a type that is
> invalid for use as a key column in an index.

To be verbose, I was trying to set the indexes like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserName", true, "IX_UserName");
}
        
public override void Down()
{
    DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "IX_UserName");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latest version released today, this should do the trick:

`modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(x => x.UserName).HasMaxLength(15);`

Comment: Where do we put this somewhere?

Comment: Hi, you'd put this in the `OnModelCreating()` method like this: `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) { modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(x => x.UserName).HasMaxLength(15); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required, MaxLength(15)]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Didn't work, this is what the `Up()` contains: `AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserName", c => c.String(nullable: false));`

Comment: @Yustme Did you re-scaffold the migration after making the change?

Comment: Yes, `Add-Migration test` that gave me the pasted `Up()`. After that, `Update-Database`. Went to the table, refreshed it, and still saw `nvarchar(max)`.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time has passed, but I think someone may still find it useful. I've had the same problem and found a clue to my solution here.
The migration mechanisms ignore the MaxLength attribute, but one can add the corrections manually:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserName", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 15, storeType: "nvarchar"));
    CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserName");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", new[] { "UserName" });
    AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserName", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256, storeType: "nvarchar"));
}
```

After `update-database` the fields are shortened and the SQL queries searching by UserName run faster (at least with mySQL which I use), because the indexes are used to search efficiently.