# ASP.NET-Identity limit UserNameIndex length

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

How can I limit the UserNameIndex UNIQUE index in the table AspNetUsers?

I am using ASP.NET Identity with a Mysql backend and am running up against another instance of:

```
Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
```

I have tried

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Secuser>().Property(x => x.UserName).HasMaxLength(100);
modelBuilder.Entity<Secuser>().Property(t => t.Id).HasMaxLength(100);
```

I have done all the standard:

```
public class Secuser : IdentityUser
 {
 [Required]
 public string FullName { get; set; }

 [Required]
 public string Address { get; set; }

 [Required]
 public string City { get; set; }

 [Required]
 public string Country { get; set; }

 [Required]
 public bool AgreeTermsOfServicePrivacyPolicy { get; set; }

 [Required]
 public string BasePath { get; set; }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Secuser>
{
 public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
 {
 }
 .....
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
  modelBuilder.Entity<Secuser>().Property(x => x.UserName).HasMaxLength(100);
  modelBuilder.Entity<Secuser>().Property(t => t.Id).HasMaxLength(100);
  .....
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
 }
```

When I issue:

```
update-database -verbose
```

the output is:

```
Using StartUp project 'sec'.
Using NuGet project 'sec'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'sec' (DataSource: localhost, Provider: MySql.Data.MySqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [201405072209015_InitialCreate].
Applying explicit migration: 201405072209015_InitialCreate.
.....
create table `AspNetUsers` (`Id` nvarchar(128)  not null ,`FullName` longtext not null ,`Address` longtext not null ,`City` longtext not null ,`Country` longtext not null ,`AgreeTermsOfServicePrivacyPolicy` bool not null ,`BasePath` longtext not null ,`Email` nvarchar(256) ,`EmailConfirmed` bool not null ,`PasswordHash` longtext,`SecurityStamp` longtext,`PhoneNumber` longtext,`PhoneNumberConfirmed` bool not null ,`TwoFactorEnabled` bool not null ,`LockoutEndDateUtc` datetime,`LockoutEnabled` bool not null ,`AccessFailedCount` int not null ,`UserName` nvarchar(256)  not null ,primary key ( `Id`) ) engine=InnoDb auto_increment=0
CREATE UNIQUE index  `UserNameIndex` on `AspNetUsers` (`UserName` DESC) using HASH
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
.....
```

I have also made the changes to allow Migration History to work:

```
public class MySqlHistoryContext : HistoryContext
 {
 public MySqlHistoryContext(DbConnection connection, string defaultSchema):base(connection,defaultSchema)
  {
  }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
  modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
  }
 }
```

It appears that the entire problem centers around

```
`UserName` nvarchar(256)

modelBuilder.Entity<Secuser>().Property(x => x.UserName).HasMaxLength(100);
```

appears to not be working. I am using EntityFramework 6.1.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.0.1.

So, it appears from looking at:

[ASP.NET-Identity limit UserName length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975717/asp-net-identity-limit-username-length)

that either I am missing something in how I implemented HasMaxLength or there is some other reason why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, if you look at the log (not that evident), it's crashing on this query :

```
CREATE UNIQUE index  `UserNameIndex` on `AspNetUsers` (`UserName` DESC) using HASH
```

When you look at your migration code, the up() function, you will see this by default :

```
 UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256, storeType: "nvarchar"),
```

I just changed the maxLength value to 196 it should work. You'll just have to remember that usernames can't be longer than 196 characters (which, I think, is really enough for 99.9% of the population)

PS : I got the same error for the "AspNetRoles" table

Comment: I keep tripping myself up with this, even after I've fixed it numerous times, now at least I have a reference point for the next time I inevitably break things again! :)

Comment: I have the exactly same problem, is there any solution to this, besides editing the migration file by hand every time?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting max length in migration code, its better to set it on the model itself. It can be done using following code.

Thanks to: Rune G @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/29059523/332188 <-- well explained here

Just copying the code from above link for easy reference

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    //... default code for ApplicationDbContext

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().Property(u => u.UserName).HasMaxLength(128);

        //Uncomment this to have Email length 128 too (not neccessary)
        //modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(128);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().Property(r => r.Name).HasMaxLength(128);
    }
}
```